# Python and Regex. Or statement

Tags: python, regex

I will explain my problem with an example. Here is two different version of my text:

Version 1:

```
Blah: 1 2345 $ blah blah blah
```

Version 2:

```
Blah: 1 2345 $ (9 8546 $) blah blah blah
```

I try to write a regex in Python where if the text is in Version 2, then it will return the number in the parenthesis. Otherwise, it will return the number outside.

```
pat = re.compile(r"Blah: [0-9]+\s[0-9]+ /$ \(([0-9]+\s[0-9]+)|Blah: ([0-9]+\s[0-9]+)")
pat.findall(text)
```

The problem is that it returns `('1 2345', '')` or `('', '9 8546')` in each case.

How can I change the regex to return only the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pretty comfortable with the RegEx you wrote, then I would suggest not to change the RegEx and get the value like this

```
print "".join(pat.findall(text)[0])
```

This will just concatenate the matching results. Since the other group captures nothing, you will get a single string.

**Note:** Also, you need to escape `$` in your RegEx, like `\$`, otherwise it will be considered as the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `findall`. The only situation in which it is useful is when you have a *simple* regex and you want to get all its matches. When you start having capturing groups it easily become quite useless.

The `finditer` method returns the actual `match` objects created during matching instead of returning the tuples of the matched groups. You can slightly modify your regex to use capturing groups:

```
pat = re.compile(r'Blah: (\d+\s\d+) \$ (\((\d+\s\d+)\s*\$\))?')
```

Afterwards to get the matched number you can use `match.group(3) or match.group(1)` to select one or the other depending whether there was a parenthesized match:

```
text = 'Blah: 1 2345 $ (9 8546 $) blah blah blah\nBlah: 1 2345 $ blah blah blah'
[m.group(3) or m.group(1) for m in pat.finditer(text)]
```

Outputs:

```
Out[12]: ['9 8546', '1 2345']
```

Comment: THe problem is that I cannot know each time which version of text someone add.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Your comment doesn't make any sense to me. What's "text someone add"? You never mentioned adding text. Who is someone?

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstood it. The texts are not predefined. A user may add in a web form a text either on Version 1 or Version 2, but I cannot know which version has added. So, if it is version 2, I want the number in the parenthesis, otherwise the number outside.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Yes, that's exactly what the code does. If the user inputs the "version 2" text, it will return the number that was specified in parenthesis, otherwise the other number.